# c++ check if string is valid regex string without exception

Tags: c++

I'm currently validating if a string is a valid regex string by using a try, catch. I'd like to instead preferably do this without a try, catch, and some sort of bool returning function.

Are there any options? (minimal version using the std)

Example using try, catch:

```
std::wstring regex;
try {
        wregex re(regex);
    }
    catch (const std::regex_error& ) {

}
```

Comment: Write a function that implements the regex logic and returns false if an exception was thrown and true otherwise

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm going to assume I haven't made it clear enough, but I want to remove exceptions completely.

Comment: If you want to use only standard library I think there aren't any options. Do you want to use a third party library?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'll see if I can wait for a std example (if there are any). I'd like to keep things minimal thus preferably no 3rd party libs

Comment: @dk123 you need to [edit] your question to add this information. Comments are for requesting clarifications. Everything that is pertinent to the question needs to be in the body of the question

Answer (score 4):

Write a function that implements the regex logic and returns false if an exception was thrown and true otherwise

```
bool isValid(const std::wstring &regex) {
    try {
        wregex re(regex);
    }
    catch (const std::regex_error& ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`boost::regex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) which can be switched into a non-throwing mode. For example:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const boost::regex valid_re("\\d+", boost::regex_constants::no_except);
  if (valid_re.status() == 0) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << regex_match("123", valid_re) << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid regex\n";
  }

  const boost::regex invalid_re("[", boost::regex_constants::no_except);
  if (invalid_re.status() == 0) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << regex_match("123", invalid_re) << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid regex\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
true
Invalid regex
```

Make sure you are calling `regex_match()` only after checking the `status()`. Calling `regex_match()` will throw an exception if the regular expression is invalid!